# How to query a Many to Many without using a relation in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Background information:**

I'm building an asset tracking system. I have a **Product** that has many **Stock**. Now, a **Stock** can be a container or a component inside of a container. Please see example below.

---

**Example**

[image: Example of container and component]

In this picture, you can see two **Products**

1. L-Acoustics LA8 (Has 40 in **Stock**) [Each **Stock** is a component inside of the container]
2. L-Acoustics LA-RAK II (Has 4 in **Stock**) [Each **Stock** is a container]

---

**My goal:**

I want to be able to show all of the containers I have with the last time it was updated. Like the picture below

[image: What I want]

**The problem:**

I can't show the last time the container was updated. Because of the way I'm accessing the relations, don't allow me to get inside the pivots and get the last updated.

**What I've tried:**

I created a Many-to-Many relationship with the **Stock** model itself and called the pivot table "component_container".

Here is the database relation pertinent to my problem:

[image: Database design]

Here is my Stock model:

```php
// Stock.php

class Stock extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'product_id' => 'integer',
        'quantity'   => 'integer'
    ];

    public function getContainerAttribute()
    {
        return $this->container()->first();
    }

    public function getComponentsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->components()->get()->flatten()->all();
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function container()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class, 'component_container', 'component_id', 'container_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function components()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class, 'component_container', 'container_id', 'component_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Here is my controller for showing my containers:

```php
// ContainerController.php

class ContainerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $containers = Stock::has('components')->paginate(20);
        return view('containers.index', compact('containers'));
    }
}
```

Here is the containers/index.blade.php

```html
// index.blade.php

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Updated</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @forelse($containers as $container)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{route('products.stocks.show', [$container->product->slug, $container->barcode])}}">
                            <strong>{{ $container->barcode }}</strong>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $container->product->name }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100" class="text-center">Nothing Available</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you can you with() and grab last updated record https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads